# sudo - impersonating a user

Tags: unix, sudo, sudoers

I am trying to use the sudo command and sudoers file correctly so that I can run a command as another user.

I have my sudoers file set up as follows:

```
beans ALL = (root,apache) NOPASSWD: /opt/renovations/var/script-*.sh
```

root, apache, and beans are part of the group beans.
Also /opt has 755 permissions, while the /opt/renovations directory and it's sub-directories are owned by the beans user and group.

The command I'm trying to run as beans is:

```
sudo -n -u apache -i /opt/renovations/var/script-test.sh
```

-n: is so that I'm not prompted for a password, as this will be run by a cron
  -u: is so that I can impersonate the apache user
  -i: is so that I simulate a login, and my .profile is loaded. I need this so that I access the environment variables in .profile

Is there something I need to update in my sudoers file so that this is possible?

Comment: It's not off-topic here but maybe you'll get a faster answer on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Move to unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks for the advices, moved to http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147847/sudo-impersonating-a-user
Question here is ready to close.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because OP has manually migrated the same question to [Unix+Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147847/sudo-impersonating-a-user) and has asked this to be closed.